# how to add tab bars?

Tags: iphone

i m having an view based application,
in my second view i want to have an 5 tabs.

but i hv no idea how to implement it.
i hv already added 5 tabs,but its not working, any tutorials or somethionng will be very helpfdul

thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this one quite helpfull back in the days when I started programming.

[Tutorial for iPhone app with UITabBarController and UINavigationController](http://21gingerman.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tutorial-and-sample-code-for-iphone-app-with-tab-bar-and-nav-bar/)

On another note:

If you start developing with the "Tab Bar Application" template from XCode things might be a little bit easier to start with.

I would also question the Design of an application that is view based and has a tabcontroller only in one of its modal views. I'm not sure if this is reason enough for your app to be rejected, but i could imagine that this sort of UI design might not be in line with [Apples iPhone Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/index.html)